# Java: Removing content from Json file

Tags: java, json, object, content-management-system

I wonder how to remove/empty an .json File.

I have found various Methods online, how to empty an JSON Objekt, however the Objekt that were given were defined and done in the very same file

**What i want**: To acces a .json File and delete all the content/empty the objekt.

How can i achieve this?
[Filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Q7K.png)

**EDIT**
@Sagar Kharab
[the Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH2Lw.png)

Comment: Well can't you just delete the file? Why not just call the delete()  function on it?

Comment: I really need this file to be there, however i would like its content to be gone

Comment: Then you can simply delete the file and create a completely new one with the exact same name. It would give the same result right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may simply truncate the file or overwrite it with "{}".

Comment: How do i do that? do i define a new JSONObjekt with the path to inventory.json then truncate?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.techiedelight.com/truncate-a-file-in-java/ there you will find several different examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(Paths.get("Path to your file").toString());
file.setWritable(true);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Paths.get("Path to your file").toString()));
bufferedOutputStream.write("{}".getBytes());
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
```

I think this should work for you.

Comment: Check the Edit!

Comment: Hi! You're getting so many errors that doesn't seem to have to do with what Sagar suggested. I'd suggest you start breaking it down and fix each exception before you come back to this specific problem. Because File's/Buffers usually would only be NullPointerException or specific FileNotFoundExceptions..these exceptions..like XML-Exception..seems to be something completly different.